# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges absolutely.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, absolute-convergence

> For the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$, suppose that there is a number $r$ with $0\leq r<1$ and a natural number $N$ such that $$|a_k|^{1/k}<r\qquad\text{for all indices $k\geq N$}$$ Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges absolutely.

Proof:

For a given $r\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq r<1$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfy $|a_k|^{1/k}<r$ for all indices $k\geq N$, that gives $|a_k|<r^k$. Now, define $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k|$ be a sequence of partial sum of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_k|$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^{n}r^k$ converges to $(1-r^{n+1})/(1-r)$, for all $\epsilon>0$, this gives $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}r^k-\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\qquad\text{for all $k\geq N$}$$ Then for all $j,k\geq N$, we have
    \begin{align*}
    \left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j-\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\right|<\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}r^j-\sum_{k=1}^{n}r^k\right|&=\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}r^j-\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}+\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}r^k\right|\\
    &\leq\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}r^j-\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\right|+\left|\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}r^k\right|\\
    &=\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon
    \end{align*}
    Hence, $\{s_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence which implies $\{s_n\}$ is convergent, so there exists an $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\leq M$. This inequality implies $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_k|$ is convergent; therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges absolutely.

---

Does this solution valid? If not, can someone give me a hint or suggestion to receive the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I get confused because you wrote $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j - \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. It is $0$. Shouldn't it be corrected as $\sum_{i=N}^j a_i - \sum_{i=N}^k a_i$?

Comment: @choco_addicted that should be $\sum_{j=N}^{n}a_j-\sum_{k=N}^{n}a_k$ ?

Comment: You have the partial sum $$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|.$$. Then $s_i-s_j=\sum_{k=1}^i |a_k|-\sum_{k=1}^j |a_k|$, not $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|-\sum_{j=1}^n |a_j|$.

Comment: One more problem: $\sum_{k=1}^n r^k$ converges to $\frac{r}{1-r}$ as $n\to\infty$, not $\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the comparison test, then you can prove the proposition easily. You know $|a_k| \le r^k$ for all $k \ge N$. Since $0\le r < 1$, the geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n$ converges. Therefore, by comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|$ converges.

The proposition you have to prove is called the 'root test'.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to prove that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$$ converges absolutely, consider the sum $$|\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k|$$ = $$|\sum_{k=0}^N a_k + \sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k|$$ $\le$ 
$$|\sum_{k=0}^N a_k| + |\sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k|$$

Notice that the first sum is convergent because it has finite terms.
The second sum is where you use the assumption given about each $|a_k|^\frac1k < r$ and that $0 \le r < 1$.

Invoking the triangle inequality, the original assumption, the ratio test and the root test should show that you have a sum of two convergent series.

Comment: I guess "$\|a_k|^\frac1k$" was meant to be "$\|a_k|^\frac1k$" - I have edited your answer. I will also point out that you can use `$\left|\sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k\right|$` to get $\left|\sum_{k=N}^\infty a_k\right|$. I.e., the size of the delimiters will be proportionate to the height of the expression between them. (It is, at least to some extent, a matter of taste which one looks better.)